# PowerAutomate: is there a way for a trigger to be fired by receiving mails for a different mailboxes

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I have a service account that should represent the flow for multiple mail-accounts. The flow is started whenever a mail arrives in a mailbox, then a confirmation should be sent after that. Let's assume I have 100 different mail-accounts in the company and the flow should be triggered for all of them, this should be bundled (dynamically) in the service account. How can this be done?
With dynamically I mean not "hardcoded" mail-accounts in the trigger (because they are changing a lot).

I never have used logic apps, but are they a better solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 ways for this

**WAY-1**

You can either use a Distributed list mail where all the members in your team are the members and trigger an email.

---

**WAY-2**

I have created a list adding the person column and adding the members to the list in SharePoint and sent mails using that column. Here is the Screenshot of the flow that I used

[image]